# Constrained least-squares estimation in Python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, least-squares

I'm trying to perform a constrained least-squares estimation using Scipy such that all of the coefficients are in the range `(0,1)` and sum to `1` (this functionality is implemented in Matlab's `LSQLIN` function).

Does anybody have tips for setting up this calculation using Python/Scipy. I believe I should be using `scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp()`, but am not entirely sure what parameters I should be passing to it.[1]

Many thanks for the help,
Nick

[1] The one example in the documentation for `fmin_slsqp` is a bit difficult for me to parse without the referenced text -- and I'm new to using Scipy.

Comment: Do you require using scipy? `cvxpy` is a convex optimization library made for this type of problems.

Answer (score 7):

[scipy-optimize-leastsq-with-bound-constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878558/scipy-optimize-leastsq-with-bound-constraints) on SO gives`leastsq_bounds`, which is
[leastsq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#least-square-fitting-leastsq)
with bound constraints such as 0 <= x_i <= 1.
The constraint that they sum to 1 can be added in the same way.
(I've found `leastsq_bounds` / MINPACK to be good on synthetic test functions in 5d, 10d, 20d;
how many variables do you have ?)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#tutorial-sqlsp), it seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

Since MATLAB's `lsqlin` is a bounded **linear** least squares solver, you would want to check out [scipy.optimize.lsq_linear](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.lsq_linear.html).

Comment: Yes, but how do I add linear constraint expressions? The documentation only seems to allow the specification of bounds on the variables.

Answer (score 0):

*Non-negative least squares* optimization using [`scipy.optimize.nnls`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html) is a robust way of doing it. Note that, if the coefficients are constrained to be positive and sum to unity, they are automatically limited to interval [0,1], that is one need not additionally constrain them from above.

`scipy.optimize.nnls` automatically makes variables positive using [Lawson and Hanson algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares), whereas the sum constraint can be taken care of as discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54895887/6151828) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33385898/6151828).

Scipy `nnls` uses an old fortran backend, which is apparently widely used in equivalent implementations of nnls by other software.