# Constrained Linear Regression in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization, linear-regression

I have a [classic linear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) regression problem of the form:

`y = X b`

where `y` is a *response vector* `X` is a *matrix* of input variables and `b` is the vector of fit parameters I am searching for.

Python provides `b = numpy.linalg.lstsq( X , y )` for solving problems of this form.

However, when I use this I tend to get either extremely large or extremely small values for the components of `b`.

I'd like to perform the same fit, but constrain the values of `b` between 0 and 255.

It looks like `scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp()` is an option, but I found it extremely slow for the size of problem I'm interested in (`X` is something like `3375 by 1500` and hopefully even larger).

1. Are there any other Python options for performing constrained least
   squares fits?
2. Or are there python routines for performing [Lasso
   Regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#LASSO_method) or Ridge Regression or some other regression method
   which penalizes large `b` coefficient values?

Comment: sklearn LASSO: https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=lasso+regression+sklearn&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recent scipy versions include a solver:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.lsq_linear.html#scipy.optimize.lsq_linear

Comment: Nice, on the surface that sounds like exactly what I need. Being able to provide weights to the `X` input variable matrix rows may actually also be very useful to me (I do have a sense of the reliability of various data points which that may let me take advantage of). I'll definitely give it a try, thanks!

Comment: It is not really good tested through, hope it will work for you. Code is pure python and should be easy to test.

Comment: `scipy.opimize.nnls` is a good tip as well. Simply constraining to non-negative values may indeed be enough. `numpy.linalg.lstsq` solutions seemed to be balancing out huge positive `b` values with equally huge negative `b` values.

Answer (score 10):

You mention you would find Lasso Regression or Ridge Regression acceptable.  These and many other constrained linear models are available in the [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) package.  Check out the [section on generalized linear models](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.linear_model).

Usually constraining the coefficients involves some kind of regularization parameter (C or alpha)---some of the models (the ones ending in CV) can use cross validation to automatically set these parameters.  You can also further constrain models to use only positive coefficents---for example, there is an option for this on the Lasso model.

Answer (score 4):

[scipy-optimize-leastsq-with-bound-constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878558/scipy-optimize-leastsq-with-bound-constraints)
on SO gives leastsq_bounds, which is [scipy leastsq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#least-square-fitting-leastsq)
+ bound constraints such as 0 <= x_i <= 255.
(Scipy leastsq wraps MINPACK, one of several implementations of the widely-used 
[Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm)
a.k.a. damped least-squares.
There are various ways of implementing bounds; leastsq_bounds is I think the simplest.)

Answer (score 2):

As @conradlee says, you can find Lasso and Ridge Regression implementations in the [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) package. These regressors serve your purpose if you just want your fit parameters to be small or positive.

However, if you want to impose any other range as a bound for the fit parameters, you can build your own constrained Regressor with the same package. See the answer by David Dale to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50410037/multiple-linear-regression-with-specific-constraint-on-each-coefficients-on-pyth) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I recently prepared some [tutorials on Linear Regression in Python](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/LinearMultivariateRegression). Here is one of the options (Gekko) that includes constraints on the coefficients.

```py
# Constrained Multiple Linear Regression
import numpy as np
nd = 100 # number of data sets
nc = 5   # number of inputs
x = np.random.rand(nd,nc)
y = np.random.rand(nd)

from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False); m.options.IMODE=2
c  = m.Array(m.FV,nc+1)
for ci in c:
    ci.STATUS=1
    ci.LOWER = -10
    ci.UPPER =  10
xd = m.Array(m.Param,nc)
for i in range(nc):
    xd[i].value = x[:,i]
yd = m.Param(y); yp = m.Var()
s =  m.sum([c[i]*xd[i] for i in range(nc)])
m.Equation(yp==s+c[-1])
m.Minimize((yd-yp)**2)
m.solve(disp=True)
a = [c[i].value[0] for i in range(nc+1)]
print('Solve time: ' + str(m.options.SOLVETIME))
print('Coefficients: ' + str(a))
```

It uses the nonlinear solver `IPOPT` to solve the problem that is better than the `scipy.optimize.minimize` solver. There are other constrained optimization methods in Python as well as discussed in [Is there a high quality nonlinear programming solver for Python?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/83/is-there-a-high-quality-nonlinear-programming-solver-for-python).