# Multiple Linear Regression with specific constraint on each coefficients on Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, constraints, linear-regression

I am currently running multiple linear regression on a dataset. At first, I didn't realize I needed to put constraints over my weights; as a matter of fact, I need to have specific positive & negative weights.

To be more precise, I am doing a scoring system and this is why some of my variables should have a positive or negative impact on the note. Yet, when running my model, the results do not fit what I am expecting, some of my 'positive' variables get negative coefficients and vice versa.

As an example, let's suppose my model is :

```
y = W0*x0 + W1*x1 + W2*x2
```

Where x2 is a 'positive' variable, I would like to put a constraint over W2 to be positive !

I have been looking around a lot about this issue but I've not found anything about constraints on specific weights/coefficients, all that I've found is about setting all coefficients positive or summing them to one.

I am working on Python using the ScikitLearn packages. This is how I get my best model :

```
def ridge(Xtrain, Xtest, Ytrain, Ytest, position):
    param_grid={'alpha':[0.01 , 0.1, 1, 10, 50, 100, 1000]}
    gs = grid_search.GridSearchCV(Ridge(), param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=3)
    gs.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain)
    hatytrain = gs.predict(Xtrain)
    hatytest = gs.predict(Xtest)
```

Any idea of how I could assign a constraint on the coefficient of a specific variable ? Probably going to be burdensome to define each constraint but I have no idea how to do otherwise.

Comment: Why do you need to use scikit-learn for this? this is just a function fitting problem, isn't it. I bet there are better packages for just that task, where constraints on the to be fit parameters can be easily specified

Comment: You might consider implementing "brick wall" constraints, in which if inside the function being fitted a constraint is violated, a very large value - and therefore a very large error - is returned. This method is somewhat crude, however as a practical matter it is easily coded and easy to test.

Answer (score 14):

Scikit-learn does not allow such constraints on the coefficients.

But you can impose any constraints on coefficients and optimize the loss with **coordinate descent** if you **implement your own estimator**. In the unconstraint case, coordinate descent produces the same result as OLS in reasonable number of iterations.

I've written a class that imposes upper and lower bounds on LinearRegression coefficients. You can extend it to use Ridge or evel Lasso penalty if you want:

```
from sklearn.linear_model.base import LinearModel
from sklearn.base import RegressorMixin
from sklearn.utils import check_X_y
import numpy as np

class ConstrainedLinearRegression(LinearModel, RegressorMixin):

    def __init__(self, fit_intercept=True, normalize=False, copy_X=True, nonnegative=False, tol=1e-15):
        self.fit_intercept = fit_intercept
        self.normalize = normalize
        self.copy_X = copy_X
        self.nonnegative = nonnegative
        self.tol = tol

    def fit(self, X, y, min_coef=None, max_coef=None):
        X, y = check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'], y_numeric=True, multi_output=False)
        X, y, X_offset, y_offset, X_scale = self._preprocess_data(
            X, y, fit_intercept=self.fit_intercept, normalize=self.normalize, copy=self.copy_X)
        self.min_coef_ = min_coef if min_coef is not None else np.repeat(-np.inf, X.shape[1])
        self.max_coef_ = max_coef if max_coef is not None else np.repeat(np.inf, X.shape[1])
        if self.nonnegative:
            self.min_coef_ = np.clip(self.min_coef_, 0, None)

        beta = np.zeros(X.shape[1]).astype(float)
        prev_beta = beta + 1
        hessian = np.dot(X.transpose(), X)
        while not (np.abs(prev_beta - beta)<self.tol).all():
            prev_beta = beta.copy()
            for i in range(len(beta)):
                grad = np.dot(np.dot(X,beta) - y, X)
                beta[i] = np.minimum(self.max_coef_[i], 
                                     np.maximum(self.min_coef_[i], 
                                                beta[i]-grad[i] / hessian[i,i]))

        self.coef_ = beta
        self._set_intercept(X_offset, y_offset, X_scale)
        return self
```

You can use this class, for example, to make all coefficients non-negative

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)
model = ConstrainedLinearRegression(nonnegative=True)
model.fit(X, y)
print(model.intercept_)
print(model.coef_)
```

This produces an output like

```
-36.99292986145538
[0.         0.05286515 0.         4.12512386 0.         8.04017956
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.02273805
 0.        ]
```

You can see that most coefficients are zero. An ordinary LinearModel would have made them negative:

```
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)
print(model.intercept_)
print(model.coef_)
```

which would return to you

```
36.49110328036191
[-1.07170557e-01  4.63952195e-02  2.08602395e-02  2.68856140e+00
 -1.77957587e+01  3.80475246e+00  7.51061703e-04 -1.47575880e+00
  3.05655038e-01 -1.23293463e-02 -9.53463555e-01  9.39251272e-03
 -5.25466633e-01]
```

You can also impose arbitrary bounds for any coefficients you choose - that's what you asked for. For example, in this setup

```
model = ConstrainedLinearRegression()
min_coef = np.repeat(-np.inf, X.shape[1])
min_coef[0] = 0
min_coef[4] = -1
max_coef = np.repeat(4, X.shape[1])
max_coef[3] = 2
model.fit(X, y, max_coef=max_coef, min_coef=min_coef)
print(model.intercept_)
print(model.coef_)
```

you would get an output

```
24.060175576410515
[ 0.          0.04504673 -0.0354073   2.         -1.          4.
 -0.01343263 -1.17231216  0.2183103  -0.01375266 -0.7747823   0.01122374
 -0.56678676]
```

**Update**. This solution can be adapted to work with constraints on linear combinations of the coeffitients (e.g. their sum) - in this case, individual constraints for each coefficient would be recalculated on each step. [This Github gist](http://gist.github.com/avidale/6668635c318aceebe0142de013a4cf77) provides an example.

**UPDATE**
Due to popularity of this question, I have created a package with my implementation of constrained linear regression: https://github.com/avidale/constrained-linear-regression.
You can install it with `pip install constrained-linear-regression`. Pull requests are welcome!

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, it seems that it is exactly what I was looking for. I will try it and give you a feedback afterwards !

Comment: This is an amazing answer. Thanks for sharing it. Even though it's a little bit late for asking, would you also know how to add a constraint to the sum of all the coefficients? For example for a stock portfolio, not only coefficients can't be negative but their sum can't be greater than 1. Thanks!

Comment: If you use coordinate descent, then on each step you update only one coefficient. Therefore, the constraint to the sum of coefficients can be represented as a lower/upper bound on this particular coefficient. The only difference is that the value of this constraint would be recalculated on each step.

Comment: Of course, you need to provide a feasible initial solution, and finding it may be a separate problem. 
If it is getting difficult, you may want to look for specialized packages for constrained optimization (like `cvxopt`), instead of coding the optimization routine by yourself

Comment: Please take a look at this gist: OLS with general linear inequality constraints  https://gist.github.com/avidale/6668635c318aceebe0142de013a4cf77

Comment: @DavidDale I have used the scipy.optimize.differential_evolution genetic algorithm to find initial parameter estimates, and have had good success with it.

Comment: @DavidDale how can I add lasso/ridge penalties to this code?

Comment: @throwawaydisplayname incorporating ridge penalty is pretty easy because the loss function is still quadratic, so you just add `beta`  to the gradient and `diag(1)` to the hessian. 
However, adding lasso will break the quadraticity of the loss, so the Newton algorithm will not work exactly. But you can use it on your own risk. I have wrapped the code with support of lasso and ridge as a PyPI package: https://github.com/avidale/constrained-linear-regression

Answer (score 1):

In version **0.24.2** of **scikit-learn**, you can force the algorithm to use positive coefficients  by using the parameter **positive=True** to the **[LinearRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)**, by multiplying the columns for which you want a negative coefficient by -1 you should get what you want.