# how to find global minimum in python optimization with bounds?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, numeric, mathematical-optimization

I have a Python function with 64 variables, and I tried to optimise it using L-BFGS-B method in the minimise function, however this method have quite a strong dependence on the initial guess, and failed to find the global minimum.

But I liked its ability to set bounds for the variables. Is there a way/function to find the global minimum while having boundaries for the variables ?

Comment: I suspect that http://math.stackexchange.com/ is a more appropriate place to ask questions like this.

Comment: Could you please describe your function a bit -- smooth / gradient / Hessian ? If you can formulate it as a sum of squares, see [scipy-optimize-leastsq-with-bound-constraints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878558/scipy-optimize-leastsq-with-bound-constraints) . See also [scicomp.stackexchange.com/search?q=bfgs](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/search?q=bfgs) .

Comment: i am designing 8 bezier curves in 3D space each with 6 control points, the function to be minimized is the merit function for these curves,which is a linear combination of 4 different parameters (lengths, radius of curvature, proximity, height order) deduced from the curves. So far ive tried scipy.minimize(), basinhopping, but im still failing to find the global minimum

Answer (score 33):

This can be done with `scipy.optimize.basinhopping`.  Basinhopping is a function designed to find the *global* minimum of an objective function.  It does repeated minimizations using the function `scipy.optimize.minimize` and takes a random step in coordinate space after each minimization.  Basinhopping can still respect bounds by using one of the minimizers that implement bounds (e.g. L-BFGS-B).  Here is some code that shows how to do this

```
# an example function with multiple minima
def f(x): return x.dot(x) + sin(np.linalg.norm(x) * np.pi)

# the starting point
x0 = [10., 10.]

# the bounds
xmin = [1., 1.]
xmax = [11., 11.]

# rewrite the bounds in the way required by L-BFGS-B
bounds = [(low, high) for low, high in zip(xmin, xmax)]

# use method L-BFGS-B because the problem is smooth and bounded
minimizer_kwargs = dict(method="L-BFGS-B", bounds=bounds)
res = basinhopping(f, x0, minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs)
print res
```

The above code will work for a simple case, but you can still end up in a forbidden region if basinhopping random displacement routine takes you there.  Luckily that can be overridden by passing a custom step taking routine using the keyword `take_step`

```
class RandomDisplacementBounds(object):
    """random displacement with bounds"""
    def __init__(self, xmin, xmax, stepsize=0.5):
        self.xmin = xmin
        self.xmax = xmax
        self.stepsize = stepsize

    def __call__(self, x):
        """take a random step but ensure the new position is within the bounds"""
        while True:
            # this could be done in a much more clever way, but it will work for example purposes
            xnew = x + np.random.uniform(-self.stepsize, self.stepsize, np.shape(x))
            if np.all(xnew < self.xmax) and np.all(xnew > self.xmin):
                break
        return xnew

# define the new step taking routine and pass it to basinhopping
take_step = RandomDisplacementBounds(xmin, xmax)
result = basinhopping(f, x0, niter=100, minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs,
                      take_step=take_step)
print result
```

Comment: A variant with no loop: `return np.clip( x + random(...), xmin, xmax )`.  (WIth the same step_size in all dimensions, prescale so the bounds box is roughly square.)

Comment: Hello. I think you need self.xmin and self.xmax in __call__ rather than xmin and xmax?

Answer (score 7):

Some common-sense suggestions for debugging and visualizing any optimizer
on your function:

Are your objective function and your constraints reasonable ?
If the objective function is a sum say `f() + g()`,
print those separately for all the `x` in `"fx-opt.nptxt"` (below);
if `f()` is 99 % of the sum and `g()` 1 %, investigate.

Constraints: how many of the components `x_i` in `xfinal` are stuck at bounds,
`x_i <= lo_i` or `>= hi_i` ?

---

How bumpy is your function on a global scale ?
Run with several random startpoints, and save the results to analyze / plot:

```
title = "%s  n %d  ntermhess %d  nsample %d  seed %d" % (  # all params!
    __file__, n, ntermhess, nsample, seed )
print title
...
np.random.seed(seed)  # for reproducible runs
np.set_printoptions( threshold=100, edgeitems=10, linewidth=100,
        formatter = dict( float = lambda x: "%.3g" % x ))  # float arrays %.3g

lo, hi = bounds.T  # vecs of numbers or +- np.inf
print "lo:", lo
print "hi:", hi

fx = []  # accumulate all the final f, x
for jsample in range(nsample):
        # x0 uniformly random in box lo .. hi --
    x0 = lo + np.random.uniform( size=n ) * (hi - lo)

    x, f, d = fmin_l_bfgs_b( func, x0, approx_grad=1,
                m=ntermhess, factr=factr, pgtol=pgtol )
    print "f: %g  x: %s  x0: %s" % (f, x, x0)
    fx.append( np.r_[ f, x ])

fx = np.array(fx)  # nsample rows, 1 + dim cols
np.savetxt( "fx-opt.nptxt", fx, fmt="%8.3g", header=title )  # to analyze / plot

ffinal = fx[:,0]
xfinal = fx[:,1:]
print "final f values, sorted:", np.sort(ffinal)
jbest = ffinal.argmin()
print "best x:", xfinal[jbest]
```

If some of the `ffinal` values look reasonably good, 
try more random startpoints near those --
that's surely better than pure random.

If the `x` s are curves, or anything real, plot the best few `x0` and `xfinal`.
(A rule of thumb is nsample ~ 5*d or 10*d  in `d` dimensions.
Too slow, too many ? Reduce `maxiter` / `maxeval`, reduce `ftol` --
you don't need `ftol` 1e-6 for exploration like this.)

If you want reproducible results,
then you must list ALL relevant parameters in the `title`
and in derived files and plots.
Otherwise, you'll be asking "where did *this* come from ??"

---

How bumpy is your function on epsilon scale ~ 10^-6 ?
Methods that approximate a gradient sometimes return their last estimate,
but if not:

```
from scipy.optimize._numdiff import approx_derivative  # 3-point, much better than
## from scipy.optimize import approx_fprime
for eps in [1e-3, 1e-6]:
    grad = approx_fprime( x, func, epsilon=eps )
    print "approx_fprime eps %g: %s" % (eps, grad)
```

If however the gradient estimate is poor / bumpy before the optimizer quit,
you won't see that.
Then you have to save all the intermediate `[f, x, approx_fprime]`
to watch them too; easy in python -- ask if that's not clear.

In some problem areas it's common to back up and restart from a purported `xmin`.
For example, if you're lost on a country road,
first find a major road, then restart from there.

---

Summary:
don't expect any black-box optimizer to work on a function that's
large-scale bumpy, or epsilon-scale bumpy, or both.
Invest in test scaffolding, and in ways to **see** what the optimizer is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Since the time you asked this question there have been some nice advances in global optimization that may serve you well. In particular, I'd draw your attention to the SHGO algorithm ([package](https://pypi.org/project/shgo/)) which is now also in scipy.optimize as one of the standard options. It may struggle with the dimensionality of your search space however, if there's really no way you can reduce it.

You might try some classics like pattern search, or surrogate methods in [PySOT](https://pypi.org/project/pySOT/0.1.20/) which [benchmark very well](https://www.microprediction.com/blog/optimize) also. If you really get stuck consider something like optuna or, if you are desperate, hyperopt.

My current choices are DLIB and Nevergrad. Both are quite fast. For an option that is free of any real dependencies, maybe take a look at freelunch.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to your detailed reply, but as im fairly new to python, i didnt quite know how to implement the code to my program, but here was my attempt at the optimisation:

```
x0=np.array((10, 13, f*2.5, 0.08,    10, f*1.5,  0.06, 20, 
             10, 14, f*2.5, 0.08,    10, f*1.75, 0.07, 20,
             10, 15, f*2.5, 0.08,    10, f*2,    0.08, 20,
             10, 16, f*2.5, 0.08,    10, f*2.25, 0.09, 20,
             10, 17, f*2.5, -0.08,    10, f*2.5, -0.06, 20,
             10, 18, f*2.5, -0.08,    10, f*2.75,-0.07, 20,
             10, 19, f*2.5, -0.08,    10, f*3,   -0.08, 20,
             10, 20, f*2.5, -0.08,    10, f*3.25,-0.09, 20))

# boundary for each variable, each element in this restricts the corresponding element     above
bnds=((1,12), (1,35), (0,f*6.75), (-0.1, 0.1),(1,35), (0,f*6.75), (-0.1, 0.1),(13, 35), 
  (1,12), (1,35), (0,f*6.75), (-0.1, 0.1),(1,35), (0,f*6.75), (-0.1, 0.1),(13, 35), 
  (1,12), (1,35), (0,f*6.75), (-0.1, 0.1),(1,35), (0,f*6.75), (-0.1, 0.1),(13, 35), 
  (1,12), (1,35), (0,f*6.75), (-0.1, 0.1),(1,35), (0,f*6.75), (-0.1, 0.1),(13, 35), 
  (1,12), (1,35), (0,f*6.75), (-0.1, 0.1),(1,35), (0,f*6.75), (-0.1, 0.1),(13, 35), 
  (1,12), (1,35), (0,f*6.75), (-0.1, 0.1),(1,35), (0,f*6.75), (-0.1, 0.1),(13, 35), 
  (1,12), (1,35), (0,f*6.75), (-0.1, 0.1),(1,35), (0,f*6.75), (-0.1, 0.1),(13, 35), 
  (1,12), (1,35), (0,f*6.75), (-0.1, 0.1),(1,35), (0,f*6.75), (-0.1, 0.1),(13, 35), )

from scipy.optimize import basinhopping
from scipy.optimize import minimize

merit=a*meritoflength + b*meritofROC + c*meritofproximity +d*(distancetoceiling+distancetofloor)+e*heightorder
minimizer_kwargs = {"method": "L-BFGS-B", "bounds": bnds, "tol":1e0}
ret = basinhopping(merit_function, x0, minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs, niter=10, T=0.01)

zoom = ret['x']
res = minimize(merit_function, zoom, method = 'L-BFGS-B', bounds=bnds, tol=1e-5)
print res
```

the merit function combines x0 with some other values to form 6 control points for 8 curves, then calculates their lengths, radii of curvature, etc. It returns the final merit as linear combinations of those parameters with some weights.

i used `basinhopping` with low precisions to find the some minima, then used `minimize` to increase the precision of the lowest munimum.

p.s. the platform i am running on is Enthoght canopy 1.3.0, numpy 1.8.0  scipy 0.13.2      mac 10.8.3

Comment: How much does your function "hop" through basins ?
would be useful for others who might try this.
And a general question: are the control points constrained to one big box,
or each in its own 1/6 th ? If one big box,
then the solution space is 6! = 720 times bigger than need be.

Comment: how do i check how much the function hops?  As for 6 control points, say P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6. In these points, P1, P6, are fixed, P2y, P2z, P5y, p5z, are fixed, hence the variables are P2x, P3x, P3y, P3z, P4x, P4y, P4z, P5x. Now i believe P3, and P4 share the same big box, while P2, P5, move on single x axis

Comment: I'd suggest a new question, something like "how do I check how a function hops, for scipy.optimize.basinhopping". But you're getting reasonable results, is that right ?