# Meaning of 'minimization_failures' when using scipy.optimize.basinhopping?

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to use `scipy.optimize.basinhopping` with a  function `b_log(x)` at point `x=10`. I do not understand the meaning of "minimization_failures" below. Can anyone explain?

```
 In [144]: scipy.optimize.basinhopping(b_log,10)
    Out[144]:
                      nfev: 6969
     minimization_failures: 101
                       fun: 420
                         x: array([10])
                   message: ['requested number of basinhopping iterations completed successfully']
                      njev: 1919
                       nit: 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [original source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/_basinhopping.py):

```
# do a local minimization
minres = self.minimizer(x_after_step) 
x_after_quench = minres.x
energy_after_quench = minres.fun
if not minres.success:
    self.res.minimization_failures += 1 
    if self.disp:
        print("warning: basinhopping: local minimization failure")
```

So, `minimization_failures` means exactly what its name says: The number of times a minimization could not be done during the monte-carlo-step.

Edit:
Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22208797/860196) for some explanation of the method. I think u may need to provide the additional arguments to the function (e.g. T and minimizer_kwargs).