# How to put constraints on fitting parameter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, curve-fitting

I want to fit a curve to my data:

```
x=[24,25,28,37,58,104,200,235,235]  
y=[340,350,370,400,430,460,490,520,550]  
xerr=[1.1,1,0.8,1.4,1.4,2.6,3.8,2,2]

def fit_fc(x, a, b, c):  
return a*x**b+c

popt, pcov=curve_fit(fit_fc,x,y,maxfev=5000)

plt.plot(x,fit_fc(x,popt[0],popt[1],popt[2]))
plt.errorbar(x,y,xerr=xerr,fmt='-o')
```

but i want to put some constraints on the a,b and c. For example I want them to be in some range, lets say between 0 and 20. How can i achieve that? I'm new in Python, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [lmfit](http://cars9.uchicago.edu/software/python/lmfit/installation.html) to constrain you parameters. For the following plot, I constrained your parameters `a` and `b` to the range `[0,20]` (which you mentioned in your post) and c to the range `[0, 400]`. The parameters you get are:

```
a:   19.9999991
b:   0.46769173
c:   274.074071
```

and the corresponding plot looks as follows:

[image]

As you can see, the model reproduces the data reasonable well and the parameters are in the given ranges.

Here is the code that reproduces the results with additional comments:

```
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, Parameter, report_fit
import numpy as np

x=[24,25,28,37,58,104,200,235,235]  
y=[340,350,370,400,430,460,490,520,550]  


def fit_fc(params, x, data):  
    a = params['a'].value
    b = params['b'].value
    c = params['c'].value

    model = np.power(x,b)*a + c
    return model - data #that's what you want to minimize

# create a set of Parameters
#'value' is the initial condition
#'min' and 'max' define your boundaries
params = Parameters()
params.add('a', value= 2, min=0, max=20) 
params.add('b', value= 0.5, min=0, max=20)
params.add('c', value= 300.0, min=0, max=400) 

# do fit, here with leastsq model
result = minimize(fit_fc, params, args=(x, y))

# calculate final result
final = y + result.residual

# write error report
report_fit(params)

#plot results
try:
    import pylab
    pylab.plot(x, y, 'k+')
    pylab.plot(x, final, 'r')
    pylab.show()
except:
    pass
```

If you constrain all of your parameters to the range `[0,20]`, the plot looks rather bad:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to have happen if the variables are out of range. You can use a simple `if` statement (in this case the program `exit()`s):

```
x = 21

if (x not in range(0, 20)):
    print("var x is out of range")
    exit()
```

Another way is to `assert` that the variable must be in the range. In this case, it's wrapped in a `try/except` block that handles the problem gracefully, and also `exit()`s like above:

```
try:
    assert(x in range(0, 20))
except AssertionError:
    print("variable x is out of range")
    exit()
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but it haven't solve my problem yet. I want the program to fit a curve to the data with a, b and c in the chosen range. I want the program to always choose the parameters from that range without any exceptions and despite the fact, that it can achieve better fitting with using a,b or c out of range.

Answer (score 0):

Scipy uses unconstrained least squares in order to fit curve parameters, so it won't be that straightforward: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.0/scipy/optimize/minpack.py#L454

What you'd probably like to do is called constrained (non-linear?, giving what you're trying to fit) least squares problem. For instance, take a look at those discussions:

- [Constrained least-squares estimation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269383/constrained-least-squares-estimation-in-python) ( *leastsq_bounds:* https://gist.github.com/denis-bz/65da931bdbf92c49e4d0 )
- [scipy.optimize.leastsq with bound constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878558/scipy-optimize-leastsq-with-bound-constraints)

Comment: It looks more like it. Thanks, I'll have to check it.