# How to include constraint to Scipy NNLS function solution so that it sums to 1

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have the following code to solve non-negative least square.
Using [scipy.nnls.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import nnls 

A = np.array([[60, 90, 120], 
              [30, 120, 90]])

b = np.array([67.5, 60])

x, rnorm = nnls(A,b)

print x
#[ 0.          0.17857143  0.42857143]
# Now need to have this array sum to 1.
```

What I want to do is to apply a constraint on `x` solution so that the it sums to 1. How can I do it?

Answer (score 23):

I don't think you can use `nnls` directly as the [Fortran code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/nnls/nnls.f) it calls doesn't allow extra constraints. However, the constraint that the equation sums to one can be introduced as a third equation, so your example system is of the form,

```
60 x1 + 90  x2 + 120 x3 = 67.5
30 x1 + 120 x2 +  90 x3 = 60
   x1 +     x2 +     x3 = 1
```

As this is now a set of linear equations, the exact solution can be obtained from `x=np.dot(np.linalg.inv(A),b)` so that `x=[0.6875, 0.3750, -0.0625]`. This requires `x3` to be negative. Therefore, there is no exact solution when `x` is positive to this problem.

For an approximate solution where `x` is constrained to be positive, this can be obtained using,

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import nnls 

#Define minimisation function
def fn(x, A, b):
    return np.sum(A*x,1) - b

#Define problem
A = np.array([[60., 90., 120.], 
              [30., 120., 90.],
              [1.,  1.,   1. ]])

b = np.array([67.5, 60., 1.])

x, rnorm = nnls(A,b)

print(x,x.sum(),fn(x,A,b))
```

which gives, `x=[0.60003332, 0.34998889, 0.]` with a `x.sum()=0.95`.

I think if you wanted a more general solution including sum constraints, you'd need to use minimise with explicit constraints/bounds in the following form,

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize 
from scipy.optimize import nnls 

#Define problem
A = np.array([[60, 90, 120], 
              [30, 120, 90]])

b = np.array([67.5, 60])

#Use nnls to get initial guess
x0, rnorm = nnls(A,b)

#Define minimisation function
def fn(x, A, b):
    return np.linalg.norm(A.dot(x) - b)

#Define constraints and bounds
cons = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x:  np.sum(x)-1}
bounds = [[0., None],[0., None],[0., None]]

#Call minimisation subject to these values
minout = minimize(fn, x0, args=(A, b), method='SLSQP',bounds=bounds,constraints=cons)
x = minout.x

print(x,x.sum(),fn(x,A,b))
```

which gives `x=[0.674999366, 0.325000634, 0.]` and `x.sum()=1`. From minimise, the sum is correct but the value of `x` is not quite right with `np.dot(A,x)=[ 69.75001902,  59.25005706]`.

Comment: In your first code block `print(x,x.sum(),fn(x,A,b))` where does `fn` comes from?

Comment: Sorry, should be fn from the second example (Ax-b). I've corrected.

Comment: Thanks. Care to look my other related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404908/best-way-to-scale-the-matrix-variables-in-scipy-linear-programming-scheme)?

Comment: I've corrected `fn` to use `np.linalg.norm` as in @chthonicdaemon answer to your linked question, which avoids the error in minimise.