# Scipy NNLS using mask

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, lmfit

I am performing non-negative least squares using scipy. A trivial example would be as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import nnls

A = np.array([[60, 70, 120, 60],[60, 90, 120, 70]], dtype='float32')
b = np.array([6, 5])
x, res = nnls(A, b)
```

Now, I have a situation where some entries in `A` or `b` can be missing (`np.NaN`). Something like,

```
A_2 = A.copy()
A_2[0,2] = np.NaN
```

Ofcourse, running NNLS on A_2, b will not work as scipy does not expect an `inf` or `nan`.

How can we perform NNLS masking out the missing entry from the computation. Effectively, this should translate to

```
Minimize |(A_2.x- b)[mask]|
```

where mask can be defined as:

```
mask = ~np.isnan(A_2)
```

In general, entries can be missing from both `A` and `b`.

Possibly helpful:

[1] [How to include constraint to Scipy NNLS function solution so that it sums to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33385898/how-to-include-constraint-to-scipy-nnls-function-solution-so-that-it-sums-to-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can compute the mask first (determine which points you want included) and then perform NNLS. Given the mask

```
In []: mask
Out[]: 
array([[ True,  True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

you can verify whether to include a point by checking if all values in a column are `True` using `np.all` along the first axis.

```
In []: np.all(mask, axis=0)
Out[]: array([ True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

This can then be used as a column mask for `A`.

```
In []: nnls(A_2[:,np.all(mask, axis=0)], b)
Out[]: (array([ 0.09166667,  0.        ,  0.        ]), 0.7071067811865482)
```

The same idea can be used for `b` to construct a row mask.

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect!