# Constraint of Ordinary Least Squares using Scipy / Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to solve the set of linear equations:

```
min || Ax - B ||^2
    for t in [0,1]

such that the coefficients x in this equation satisfy the linear equation:

C x = D
```

This system attempts to fit a set of Polynomials to approximate a function F(t) over the range of t.

- A is a matrix, representing the map of the set of polynomials over the range of t values
- x is a vector of coefficients (what I want) corresponding to a weight applied to each polynomial in A
- B is a vector representing the F(t) values,
- C is a matrix and D a vector, which together represent the boundary conditions on the coefficients of this system

This is a case of solving linear equations using the [constraint of ordinary least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Constrained_estimation).

While there are known closed form solutions e.g. [Karush-Kuhn-Tucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) I'm looking for a routing in `scipy` / `numpy` that can be used to solve this.

Research has shown the [`scipy.optimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#constrained-multivariate) module, which includes functions such as:

[scipy.optimize.least_squares](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) .

[scipy.optimize.nnls](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html) .

[scipy.optimize.lsq_linear](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.lsq_linear.html) .

The above is suggested both from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269383/constrained-least-squares-estimation-in-python) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878558/scipy-optimize-leastsq-with-bound-constraints).

But these do not have conditions that work for a constraint of some other linear equation. What can I use in `scipy` and `numpy` to do this?

Comment: what is variable `t`

Comment: @jf328 edited q

Comment: Analytical solution should be the first to go. If you definitely want to use scipy routine, probably put the constraint as a penalization in the objective. `A2 = [A;m*C], B2 = [B;m*D]` and solve OLS `||A2.x-B2||^2` with large `m`

Comment: Just use scipy.optimize.minimize (and provide your own gradient for stability). And if your t in [0,1] is a variable-bound, i don't see the closed-form solution mentioned here multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

For this you may use `scipy.minimize(method='SLSQP')`. The documentation is [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-slsqp.html#optimize-minimize-slsqp).

You can define the equality constraint as a callable function with the signature:

```
def cons1(x):
    return sum(D - C*x)
```

[SLSQP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_quadratic_programming) essential uses the constraint then to drive your optimisation problem. Note that this is a gradient based decent, so you will most likely find a local minima to high dimensional problems.

Another option is `scipy.minimize(method=’trust-constr’)`, the documentation is [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-trustconstr.html#optimize-minimize-trustconstr). These methods are natively implemented in python so the source code and modifications are accessible through.

If you have a smooth monotonic or context function, in my experience `SLSQP` should suffice.